# use of dominate

Tags: vocabulary

Mr. A has two qualities.He is kind. He is aggressive. He is more kind than being aggressive. 
If we say:
'His kindness dominates his aggressiveness.'
'His kindness overshadows his aggressiveness.'
'His kindness surpasses his aggressiveness.'
 Which one is better?

Answer (score 2):

*X dominates Y* essentially means X *controls* Y.

If you simply want to say there is more of X than Y, *dominate* isn't the right word, but *overshadows* and *surpasses* can work.

*X surpasses Y* implies that X is moving forward or growing.  If this is not the case *overshadows* is the best term.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say that he is more frequently kind than he is aggressive, but that he nevertheless can be aggressive sometimes, then "dominate" is probably too strong a word, implying that kindness is always the dominant feature.

I suggest "moderates".

Moderate, verb: To cause to be less extreme, intense, or violent. Source: thefreedictionary